# Find the distance from camera to vanishing point in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, coordinates, vanishing-point

I have this program that finds the vanishing point for a given set of images. Is there a way to find the distance from the camera and the vanishing point?

Also once the vanishing point is found out, I manually need to find the X and Y coordinates using the tool provided in matlab. How can i code a snippet that writes all the X and Y coordinates into a text or excel file?

Also is there a better and simpler way to find the vanishing point in matlab?

***Matlab Calling Function to find Vanishing Point:***

```
clear all; close all;
dname = 'Height';
files = dir(dname);
files(1) = [];
files(1) = [];
for i=1:size(files, 1)
    original = imread(fullfile(dname, files(i).name));
    original = imresize(original,0.35);    
    im = im2double(rgb2gray(original)); 
    [row, col] = findVanishingPoint(im);
    imshow(original);hold;plot(col,row,'rx');
    saveas(gcf,strcat('Height_Result',num2str(i)),'jpg');
    close
end
```

***The findVanishingPoint function:***

```
function [row, col] = findVanishingPoint(im)

DEBUG = 0;

IM = fft2(im);
ROWS = size(IM,1); COLS = size(IM,2);


PERIOD = 2^floor(log2(COLS)-5)+2;
SIZE = floor(10*PERIOD/pi);  
SIGMA = SIZE/9; 
NORIENT = 72; 
E = 8;  
[C, S] = createGaborBank(SIZE, PERIOD, SIGMA, NORIENT, ROWS, COLS, E);


D = ones(ROWS, COLS); 
AMAX = ifftshift(real(ifft2(C{1}.*IM)).^2+real(ifft2(S{1}.*IM))).^2; 
for n=2:NORIENT
    A = ifftshift(real(ifft2(C{n}.*IM)).^2+real(ifft2(S{n}.*IM))).^2;
    D(find(A > AMAX)) = n;        
    AMAX = max(A, AMAX);        
    if (DEBUG==1)
        colormap('hot');subplot(131);imagesc(real(A));subplot(132);imagesc(real(AMAX));colorbar;
        subplot(133);imagesc(D);
        pause
end
end

if (DEBUG==2)
figure('DoubleBuffer','on');
end
T = mean(AMAX(:))-3*std(AMAX(:));
VOTE = zeros(ROWS, COLS);
for row=round(1+SIZE/2):round(ROWS-SIZE/2) 
    for col=round(1+SIZE/2):round(COLS-SIZE/2)
        if (AMAX(row,col) > T)
            indices = lineBresenham(ROWS, COLS, col, row, D(row, col)*pi/NORIENT-pi/2);
            VOTE(indices) = VOTE(indices)+AMAX(row,col);
        end
    end
    if (DEBUG==2)
        colormap('hot');imagesc(VOTE);pause;                                        
end
end
if (DEBUG==2)
close
end

M=1;
[b index] = sort(-VOTE(:));
col = floor((index(1:M)-1) / ROWS)+1;
row = mod(index(1:M)-1, ROWS)+1;
col = round(mean(col));
row = round(mean(row));
```

***The creatGaborBank function:***

```
function [C, S] = createGaborBank(SIZE, PERIOD, SIGMA, NORIENT, ROWS, COLS, E)

if (length(NORIENT)==1)
    orientations=[1:NORIENT];
else
    orientations = NORIENT;
    NORIENT = max(orientations);
end

for n=orientations
    [C{n}, S{n}] = gabormask(SIZE, SIGMA, PERIOD, n*pi/NORIENT);
    C{n} = fft2(padWithZeros(C{n}, ROWS, COLS)); 
    S{n} = fft2(padWithZeros(S{n}, ROWS, COLS));
end
```

***The gabormask function:***

```
function [cmask, smask] = gabormask(Size, sigma, period, orient, E)
if nargin < 5; E = 8; end;
if nargin < 4; orient = 0; end;
if nargin < 3; period = []; end;
if nargin < 2; sigma = []; end;
if nargin < 1; Size = []; end;

if isempty(period) & isempty(sigma); sigma = 5; end;
if isempty(period); period = sigma*2*sqrt(2); end;
if isempty(sigma); sigma = period/(2*sqrt(2)); end;
if isempty(Size); Size = 2*round(2.575*sigma) + 1; end; 

if length(Size) == 1
    sx = Size-1; sy = sx;
elseif all(size(Size) == [1 2])
    sy = Size(1)-1; sx = Size(2)-1;
else
    error('Size must be scalar or 1-by-2 vector');
end;

hy = sy/2; hx = sx/2;
[x, y] = meshgrid(-hx:sx-hx, -hy:sy-hy);

omega = 2*pi/period;
cs = omega * cos(orient);
sn = omega * sin(orient);
k = -1/(E*sigma*sigma);

g = exp(k * (E*x.*x + y.*y));   
xp = x * cs + y * sn;           
cx = cos(xp);                   
cmask = g .* cx;               
sx = sin(xp);                  
smask = g .* sx;               

cmask = cmask - mean(cmask(:));
cmask = cmask/sum(abs(cmask(:)));
smask = smask - mean(smask(:));
smask = smask/sum(abs(smask(:)));
```

***The padWithZeros function:***

```
function out = padWithZeros(in, ROWS, COLS)
out = padarray(in,[floor((ROWS-size(in,1))/2) floor((COLS-size(in,2))/2)],0,'both');
if size(out,1) == ROWS-1
    out = padarray(out,[1 0],0,'pre');
end
if size(out,2) == COLS-1
    out = padarray(out,[0 1],0,'pre');
end
```

***The findHorizonEdge function:***

```
function row = findHorizon(im)
DEBUG = 2;

ROWS = size(im,1); COLS = size(im,2);
e = edge(im,'sobel', [], 'horizontal');
dd = sum(e, 2);
N=3;
row = 1; 
M = 0;
for i=1+N:length(dd)-N
    m = sum(dd(i-N:i+N));    
    if (m > M)
        M = m;
        row = i;
    end
end
imshow(e);pause
```

***The findHorizon function:***

```
function row = findHorizon(im)
DEBUG = 2;

IM = fft2(im);
ROWS = size(IM,1); COLS = size(IM,2);

PERIOD = 2^floor(log2(COLS)-5)+2; 
SIZE = floor(10*PERIOD/pi);  
SIGMA = SIZE/9; 
NORIENT = 72; 
E = 16; 
orientations = [NORIENT/2-10:NORIENT/2+10]; 

[C, S] = createGaborBank(SIZE, PERIOD, SIGMA, orientations, ROWS, COLS, E);

ASUM = zeros(ROWS, COLS);
for n=orientations
    A = ifftshift(real(ifft2(C{n}.*IM)).^2+real(ifft2(S{n}.*IM))).^2;
    ASUM = ASUM + A;        
    if (DEBUG==1)
        colormap('hot');subplot(131);imagesc(real(A));subplot(132);imagesc(real(AMAX));colorbar;
        pause
end
end

ASUM(1:round(1+SIZE/2), :)=0; ASUM(end-round(SIZE/2):end, :)=0;
ASUM(:,end-round(SIZE/2):end)=0; ASUM(:, 1:1+round(SIZE/2))=0;
dd = sum(ASUM, 2);
[temp, row] = sort(-dd);
row = round(mean(row(1:10)));
if (DEBUG == 2)
    imagesc(ASUM);hold on;line([1:COLS],repmat(row,COLS));
    pause
end
```

***The lineImage function:***

```
function v = lineimage(x0, y0, angle, s) 

if (abs(tan(angle)) > 1e015)
    a(1,:) = repmat(x0,s(1),1)';
    a(2,:) = [1:s(1)];
elseif (abs(tan(angle)) < 1e-015)
    a(2,:) = repmat(y0,s(2),1)';
    a(1,:) = [1:s(2)];
else

    k = tan(angle);
    hiX = round((1-(s(1)-y0+1)+k*x0)/k);
    loX = round((s(1)-(s(1)-y0+1)+k*x0)/k);
    temp = max(loX, hiX);
    loX = max(min(loX, hiX), 1);
    hiX = min(s(2),temp);
    a(1,:) = [loX:hiX];
    a(2,:) = max(1, floor(s(1)-(k*a(1,:)+(s(1)-y0+1)-k*x0)));
end
v = (a(1,:)-1).*s(1)+a(2,:);
```

***The lineVector function:***

```
function [abscissa, ordinate] = linevector(x0, y0, angle, s) 

if (rad2deg(angle) == 90) 
        abscissa = repmat(x0,s(1),1);
        ordinate = [1:s(1)];
else
    k = tan(angle);
    hiX = round((1-(s(1)-y0+1)+k*x0)/k);
    loX = round((s(1)-(s(1)-y0+1)+k*x0)/k);
    temp = max(loX, hiX);
    loX = max(min(loX, hiX), 1);
    hiX = min(s(2),temp);

    abscissa = [loX:hiX];
    ordinate = k*abscissa+((s(1)-y0+1)-k*x0);
end
```

***The lineBresenham function:***

```
function [i] = lineBresenham(H,W,Sx,Sy,angle)

k = tan(angle);
if (angle == pi || angle == 0)
    Ex = W;
    Ey = Sy;
    Sx = 1;
elseif (angle == pi/2)
    Ey = 1;
    i = (Sx-1)*H+[Ey:Sy];
    return;
elseif k>0 & k < (Sy-1)/(W-Sx) 
    Ex = W;
    Ey = round(Sy-tan(angle)*(Ex-Sx));
elseif k < 0 & abs(k) < (Sy-1)/(Sx-1) 
    Ex = 1;
    Ey = round(Sy-tan(angle)*(Ex-Sx));
else
    Ey = 1;   
    Ex = round((Sy-1)/tan(angle)+Sx);
end
Dx = Ex - Sx;
Dy = Ey - Sy;
iCoords=1;
if(abs(Dy) <= abs(Dx))
    if(Ex >= Sx)
        D = 2*Dy + Dx;
        IncH = 2*Dy;
        IncD = 2*(Dy + Dx);
        X = Sx;
        Y = Sy;
        i(iCoords) = (Sx-1)*H+Sy;
        iCoords = iCoords + 1;
        while(X < Ex)
            if(D >= 0)
                D = D + IncH;
                X = X + 1;
            else
                D = D + IncD;
                X = X + 1;
                Y = Y - 1;
            end
            i(iCoords) = (X-1)*H+Y;
            iCoords = iCoords + 1;                
        end
    else 
        D = -2*Dy + Dx;
        IncH = -2*Dy;
        IncD = 2*(-Dy + Dx);
        X = Sx;
        Y = Sy;
        i(iCoords) = (Sx-1)*H+Sy;
        iCoords = iCoords + 1;
        while(X > Ex)
            if(D <= 0)
                D = D + IncH;
                X = X - 1;
            else
                D = D + IncD;
                X = X - 1;
                Y = Y - 1;
            end
            i(iCoords) = (X-1)*H+Y;
            iCoords = iCoords + 1;   
        end
    end


else 
    Tmp = Ex;
    Ex = Ey;
    Ey = Tmp;
    Tmp = Sx;
    Sx = Sy;
    Sy = Tmp;
    Dx = Ex - Sx;
    Dy = Ey - Sy;
    if(Ex >= Sx)
        D = 2*Dy + Dx;
        IncH = 2*Dy;
        IncD = 2*(Dy + Dx);
        X = Sx;
        Y = Sy;
        i(iCoords) = (Sy-1)*H+Sx;
        iCoords = iCoords + 1;
        while(X < Ex)
            if(D >= 0)
                D = D + IncH;
                X = X + 1;
            else
                D = D + IncD;
                X = X + 1;
                Y = Y - 1;
            end
            i(iCoords) = (Y-1)*H+X;
            iCoords = iCoords + 1;   
        end
    else
        D = -2*Dy + Dx;
        IncH = -2*Dy;
        IncD = 2*(-Dy + Dx);
        X = Sx;
        Y = Sy;
        i(iCoords) = (Sy-1)*H+Sx;
        iCoords = iCoords + 1;
        while(X > Ex)
            if(D <= 0)
                D = D + IncH;
                X = X - 1;
            else
                D = D + IncD;
                X = X - 1;
                Y = Y - 1;
            end
            i(iCoords) = (Y-1)*H+X;
            iCoords = iCoords + 1;   
        end
    end        
end
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The vanishing point is at infinity hence the distance to the camera is of no use.
2. Use `xlswrite` or `dlmwrite` to write into excel or text file respectively.

Comment: Once a photo is taken, the vanishing point is not at infinity. It intersects at one point in the image. you can find the X and Y coordinates, but what about the Z coordinates?

Comment: @CamelUno The 3D homogeneous coordinates of the vanishing point are (x,y,z,0) which means that the point is at infinity [see slide 4](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ian/Teaching/CompGeom/lec2.pdf).

Comment: It is the projection of parallel lines from infinity. So basically you can find where they fall with respect to two planes and define a line for the images as the vanishing points change with respect to the movement of the camera. It can be determined. [Vanishing lines](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67893/ivc02-vanpoint.pdf)

Comment: @CamelUno I think you are slightly confused between the 2D and 3D meaning of the vanishing point. So the vanishing is defined as the point where **parallel 3D** lines intersect which is only at infinity otherwise the lines aren't parallel. But if you project the whole setting into 2D you get a **2D** point where those lines intersect and this point can be finite. The paper you referenced use only the **2D projection** of the vanishing point. But a 2D point has no depth and thus the distance to the camera cannot be calculated.

Comment: denahiro is right.  When talking about locating something in an image you are talking about 2d coordinates and the distance to camera does not have much meaning.  You might want to re-word your question.  It sounds like you just want the x,y coordinates of the vanishing point which is a very legitimate question.  Your question title however does not make much sense.  As a side note, is your camera calibrated?  If so finding the vanishing point is very very easy.